# why jsoup nextSibling() is null?

Tags: nullpointerexception, jsoup, frontend

```
   Document document = Jsoup.parse("<p><strong>Chapter One</strong></p><p>A piece of computer code</p><p><strong>Chapter Two</strong></p><p>Java in 10 minutes</p><br>");
    Elements titles = document.getElementsByTag("strong");
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
        Node node = titles.get(i).nextSibling();            
        if (node != null) System.out.println("sib = " + node.toString());
    }
```

Hi guys, I want to get the content after strong, like I try to save Chapter One and also get the "A piece of Elements titles", but why my code shows nothing and nextSibling is null? Thanks

Comment: Because `strong `doesn't have sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because every `<strong>` element don't have any siblings, because they are the only children of listed paragraphs. According to your expectations you should ask for a parent sibling, for example:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("<p><strong>Chapter One</strong></p><p>A piece of computer code</p><p><strong>Chapter Two</strong></p><p>Java in 10 minutes</p><br>");
Elements titles = document.getElementsByTag("strong");
for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
    Element node = (Element) titles.get(i).parent().nextSibling();
    if (node != null) {
        System.out.println("sib = " + node.text());
    }
}
```

You can also cast `Node` to `Element` to use `Element.getText()` method that will return inner text from selected sibling paragraph. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Grace great! :) You can mark my answer as a correct one :)

Comment: it is very helpful if you can help me with another similar question on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081205/how-to-get-contents-between-two-tags-in-jsoup-javascript    Thanks~