# How to get contents between two tags in jsoup/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, jsoup

```
<p><strong>Chapter One</strong></p><p>A piece of computer code</p>    
<table>
 <tr>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th> 
 <th>Age</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>Jill</td>
 <td>Smith</td>
 <td>50</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><strong>Chapter Two</strong></p><p>Java in 10 minutes</p>
```

How to get contents between those two “strong” so I can get the Chapter One will have "A piece of computer code" and the table? The nextSibling() of "strong" can only retrieve one element, how to get all elements until I met another "strong"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this format going to be consistent? If so, you can simply query `nextSibling` twice for the strong element's parent (p).

If it's going to vary, you might need to manually check when to stop iterating through the siblings, such as verifying if the sibling contains a strong element.

It all depends on the full context.

Here's example with basic loops. You may want to add more checks or better queries given a different situation.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
List<Elements> data = new ArrayList<>();
Elements chapters = doc.select("p > strong");
for (Element chapter : chapters) {
    if (!chapter.ownText().toLowerCase().contains("chapter"))
        continue; //we've reached a strong element that isn't actually a chapter
    List<Element> siblings = new ArrayList<>();
    Element next = chapter.nextElementSibling();
    while (next != null) {
        if (next.ownText().toLowerCase().contains("chapter"))
            break; //we've reached the end of this chapter
        siblings.add(next);
        next = next.nextElementSibling();
    }
    data.add(new Elements(siblings));
}
```

Comment: it is not consistent~

Comment: What further information do we know then? If we know that every Chapter is in a strong element, in another p element, then we can just iterate ourselves and check the sibling for a strong element each time.

Comment: it is more like iterate nextUntil we found next strong, but cannot find similar method in Jsoup

Comment: So have you tried a while loop and breaking when there are no more siblings or if the sibling has a strong element?

Comment: I found a more silly way that to get the index of all "strong"，and then subList them between indices. Very verbose~ not sure if any better solutions

Comment: @Grace I've added an example above. You just may need to be careful, especially if the web page isn't yours. Not all strong elements may be chapter heads, and depending on the situation, they might not all be siblings of one another as well.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, the code works very well! Marked your answer~